# How to post json data using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I will try below logic, but its not working.

In Angular JS:

```
    $scope.Save = function () {

    var items = $scope.invoice.items;
    var obj = [{ sMemberCode: 'ALMA0502' }];


    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: sServiceURL + 'SaveData',
        data: obj
    });

};
```

In WCF Service :

[OperationContract]

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SaveData",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    bool SaveData(WcfService1.Common obj);
```

please tell me what I am wrong...

Comment: `its not working` is not a proper problem description

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.post = function (ItemDetails) {
    $http.post('http://localhost:4191/Service1.svc/addItemMaster', ItemDetails).
        success(function (data) {
            console.log('data', data);
            // when call is successful you code here 
        }).
        error(function (err){
            console.log('Error:', err);
        });
};
```

Did you inject $http service in your controller? 
Something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('youAppModule', []);
app.controller('controllerName',['$http', function($http){

// the above code in here 

}]);
```

Comment: thank you. I want to post json data and how to receive in wcf service?